# For Loop leaves unwanted rows behind

Tags: excel, vba

...because the row is only evaluated once and the next row is called for evaluation. But the next row is now the previous row.  How do I account for this?

```
For i = 5 To Range("A" & "65536").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i), "#N/A") = 1 Then
Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete your rows all at once, using `Union`. Like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim deleteRange As Range

    For i = 5 To Range("A" & "65536").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i), "#N/A") = 1 Then
            If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleteRange = Range("A" & i).EntireRow
            Else: Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, Range("A" & i).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    deleteRange.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop backwards (and use Rows.Count rather than hard-coding 65536) as new versions of Excel have a capacity of more than a million rows.

```
For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 5 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i), "#N/A") = 1 Then
        Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Was going to add that there are more efficient ways of doing this, such as using AutoFilter - see CallumDA's for another approach.